# Redux: Array or Object for storing a list of blogs?

Tags: javascript, arrays, redux, react-redux

I am working on designing the Redux side of an application, specifically my State Object.

I am going to make use of a POST API similar to this:

```
/api/posts
```

with a method of POST.

If I was following rules I have used in the past I would end up with a posts property and an activePost property on my global State Object.

The posts property which would presumably be produced by their posts reducers would probably be an array and it would contain the list of all the different posts I have inside the application.

I want to store my list of posts inside of an Object rather than an array and just completely eliminate the need for the activePost. So it would look like this:

```
{
  4: {title: 'Hello', id: 4, content: 'Hi', tags: 'greetings'},
  12: {title: 'Bye', id: 12, content: 'Bye', tags: 'greetings'},
}
```

Notice that inside of this object, I am saying that the key is the id of the post and the value is the post itself. So the object starts at the number 4 and closes at the ending curly brace. It has an id of 4 and using a key of 4 because its the id of the post. Same thing for the next one below.

The reason for this is to make it easier to find a particular post out of all the posts I fetch.

Can this work even with large sets of posts? Would this be best practice? Why or why not? If this does not serve any purpose, please provide a documented reason. Thank you.

Comment: Hey, i don't edit permission. So can you please add some more tags to it like redux, javascript. This way it will reach more audience. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it is best practice, in fact, a very advanced concept. I have heard colleagues say an array works best for large data sets, but not much documentation to back up their claims.

This would probably require a very challenging refactor with something like:

```
state.posts[postId]
```

and this would return the given post, the postId coming from the id number from the url and then using that number to look up against the object of the many different posts.

My understanding is that this is how its done in production and with large applications that scale well, so it actually would work with large data.